# Vertex AI - unable to tune large model - error: "Found error in at least 101 examples"

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I was able to submit jsonl file in Vertex workbench. The tunning job started and failed at veritex-pipelines-prompt-validation. When I submitted file it went through.

What is the proper jsonl format?

I tried to reformat file but no success.